# ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be applied to Android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I keep getting the error saying ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be applied to v7.widget.Toolbar and because I looked at how others fixed a similar issue they are now both support library files but the error doesn't go away for some reason.

The error says `ActionBarDrawerToggle()` in `ActionBarDrawerToggle` cannot be applied to `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` then under actual argument `R.id.drawable_ic_drawer (int)`

```js
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

```js
 mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
```

The part which is said to be making the error is R.drawer.ic_drawer. How do I resolve it?

Comment: You need to pass `toolbar` instead of `R.drawable.ic_drawer` in constructor. @Vimbainashe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ActionBarDrawerToggle Constructor is as follow.

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity,
DrawerLayout drawerLayout, 
Toolbar toolbar, 
int openDrawerContentDescRes, 
int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

You are passing `R.drawable.ic_drawer` drawable instead of toolbar that's why you are getting this error.

Create a toolbar and add it as action bar and pass this toolbar to this constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was very informative and helpful!! :) .@Pooja

Comment: But [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#OpenClose) on the official developers page, they are using `R.drawable.ic_drawer` instead of `toobar`

Comment: @eMAD The link which you referred, is using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` v4. You can find it here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html. And it is deprecated. My answer is according to `ActionBarDrawerToggle` v7.  You can find it here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to solve it, is to import `import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` instead of `import android.support.v7.widget.DrawerLayout`

According to the google documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Comment: This feature is now deprecated.

Comment: import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;  will work fine